# How to add ajax loading icon after click add to cart button on woocommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I would like to add a loading icon after a user clicks on add to cart for an item on woocommerce single page.

i am using below code in my site

```
jQuery('a.add_to_cart_button').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).append('<img src="/spinner.gif" width="20px" height="20px"/>')});
```

But this code displaying the Load icon on Add to cart Button. I want to show the Spinner on the website like as checkout page spinner.

Also It works well after user clicks the 'Add to Cart' button, but I want to remove this icon after successful execution.

Please help me !!

Comment: provide your site url.

Comment: I cant publish here

Comment: do you have hangout ?

Comment: If it's already adding a product from single product page via `ajax` then you might not need to write javascript to add a spinner. Check when you click on `add to cart` is there any class added or removed?

Comment: My problem is with now loader position

Comment: https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/shop/

Comment: Check the link
When you will click on add to cart  `loading` class added and after added to cart `loading` replaced with `added` class. Now you can add a css spinner to `loading` class. That'll do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code your current active theme functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_trigger_ajax_add_to_cart' );
function custom_trigger_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
                    ///Your action
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
```